# listview onclick listerner gives wrong row item

Tags: android, listview

I have an issue with the flow of my app.

I have one ListView in one of our fragments.
We have created one custom adapter to populate the data from a webservice with JSON. (which extends BaseAdapter)

It has other components like EditText and buttons when I set OnClick.

We have created OnClickListerner() which works correct for data. But, I want to get the next element in the same row. The position value gives the wrong row's object.

Sample code I wrote for achieves this. Please check if I have made any mistake in calling. (I'm getting data correctly from the array, but the object alone comes wrongly).

```
add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               int p = position;

            Integer pos = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
            SKU_CODE = data.get(pos).get("sku_code");
            SKU_NAME = data.get(pos).get("sku_name");
            sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
            LOGGED = sp.getBoolean("LOGGED", false);
            USER_ID = sp.getString("USER_ID", "");
            STORE_CODE = sp.getString("STORE_CODE", "985");
            url = "http://foodworld.in/android-api/add_item_to_cart.php";
            //Toast.makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("add to cart ur: ", url);
            add_to_cart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //qty_change_row.setTag(pos);

            qty_change_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AddItemToShoppingCart newTask = new AddItemToShoppingCart(arg0, pos);
            newTask.execute();

            }
        });
```

In that code we have "add_to_cart_row". This is Linear Layout with the id we are referring here. I tried setting visibility, but it's not working; it sets for the wrong object (object in other row in screen).

In the screenshot attached, I clicked on the the first product's Add to cart button.  It enabled the element in the last row (+- textbox).

This was my problem.  Please help me out.

Comment: if you use `ListView` then there is `OnItemClickListener` that provides item `position`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

I have doubt over `Integer pos = (Integer) arg0.getTag();` pos as Adapter's `getView()` returns Recycle View so possible you will get wrong data position,

So instead of it you can use `int p = position;`

Like,

```
int p = position;
SKU_CODE = data.get(p).get("sku_code");
SKU_NAME = data.get(p).get("sku_name");
```

Second Use if - else for `add_to_cart` Visibility.

Like,

```
if(//Some condition)
{
  add_to_cart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  qty_change_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
 add_to_cart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 qty_change_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace onClick with setOnItemClickListener.

Example:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               ...
            }
        });
```

You can get value or position from listview on this way:

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             QuestionItem questionItem = (QuestionItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

             if(questionItem.id == 1){
              //do something
             }
             if(position == 2){
             // do something
             }
          }
  });
```

QuestionItem is object for ListAdapter:

```
private class QuestionItem{
        private int id;

        public QuestionItem(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```